# Return value in column 1 when value in column 2 exceeds 2 for 1st time

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe called "new_dat" containing the time (days) in column t, and temperature data (and occaisionally NA) in columns A - C (please see the example in the code below):

```
> new_dat
     t    A    B    C
1  0.00 0.82 0.88 0.46
2  0.01 0.87 0.94 0.52
3  0.02   NA   NA   NA
4  0.03 0.95 1.03 0.62
5  0.04 0.98 1.06 0.67
6  0.05 1.01 1.09 0.71
7  0.06 2.00 1.13 2.00
8  0.07 1.06 1.16 0.78
9  0.08 1.07 1.18 0.81
10 0.09 1.09 1.20 0.84
11 0.10 1.10 1.21 0.86
12 0.11 2.00 1.22 0.87
```

Here is a dput() of the dataframe:

```
structure(list(t = c(0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 
0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.11), A = c(0.82, 0.870000000000001, NA, 
0.949999999999999, 
0.979999999999997, 1.01, 2, 1.06, 1.07, 1.09, 1.1, 2), B = 
c(0.879999999999999, 
0.940000000000001, NA, 1.03, 1.06, 1.09, 1.13, 1.16, 1.18, 1.2, 
1.21, 1.22), C = c(0.460000000000001, 0.520000000000003, NA, 
0.619999999999997, 0.669999999999998, 0.709999999999997, 2, 
0.780000000000001, 
0.809999999999999, 0.84, 0.859999999999999, 0.87)), .Names = c("t", 
"A", "B", "C"), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

As output, I want a vector (list?) of the values of column t where the temperature reading from columns A-C >= 2 for the first time (and only the first time), or - if the temperature is never >= 2 - return the last time reading in column t (0.11 in my example).  So 'A' would return the value 0.06 (and not 0.11), 'B' would have the value 0.11 and 'C' 0.06.  I intended to use the vector generated to create a new dataframe something like this:

```
      A    B    C
    0.06 0.11 0.06
```

I'm inexperienced with R (and code in general) so, despite reading that looping can be ineficient (but not really understanding how to accomplish what i want without it), I tried to solve this by looping first by column and then by row as follows:

```
#create blank vector to add my results to
aer <- c()

#loop by column, then by row, adding values according to the if statement
for (c in 2:ncol(new_dat)){
  c <- c
  for (r in 1:nrow(new_dat)){
    r <- r
    if ((!is.na(new_dat[r,c] )) & (new_dat[r,c] >= 2)){
      aer <- c(aer, new_dat$t[r])
    }
  }
}
```

This returns my vector, aer, as:

```
> aer
[1] 0.06 0.11 0.06
```

So it's returning both instances where 'A' is 2, and the one from column 'C'.

I dont know how to instruct the loop to stop and move to the next column after finding one instance where my 'if' statement is true.  I also tried adding an 'else' to cover the situation where temperature doesnt exceed 2:

```
else {
  aer <- c(aer, new_dat$t[nrow(new_dat)])
```

But this did not work.

I would appreciate any help in completing the code, or suggestions for a better solution.

Comment: Check your requirements, literally none of your columns differ by more than 2 (cf. your description of A-C >= 2), and, as far as I can see, for all rows B > A > C (except where A == 2.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

new_dat %>%
  gather(col, temp, -t) %>%   # reshape data
  na.omit() %>%               # remove rows with NAs
  group_by(col) %>%           # for each column value
  summarise(v = ifelse(is.na(first(t[temp >= 2])), last(t), first(t[temp >= 2]))) %>%  # return the last t value if there are no temp >=2 otherwise return the first t with temp >= 2
  spread(col, v)              # reshape again

# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#      A     B     C
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#   1  0.06  0.11  0.06
```

This solution will create the dataframe for you automatically, instead of returning a vector for you to create the dataframe yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  I am having trouble installing the tidyverse library, however some of the packages have installed.  Can you tell me which packages are required to use your solution?  I took a guess at dplyr and tidyr, but I get "Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Unsupported vector type language"

Comment: Yes, those are the 2 packages indeed. Maybe you have older versions of those? I'm using `dplyr 0.7.6` and `tidyr 0.8.1`

Comment: Thanks - you are spot on, i am running older versions of both.  Still getting errors when i try to install - will look into this some more.  Thanks again for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: I have marked this as the solution as it created the dataframe i want directly.

Comment: The only part i dont quite understand is the 'summarise' portion.  Is this checking as follows:  if `first(t[temp >= 2])` returns NA, return the last value of `t`; else return the first time `t` is `>=2` ?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I don't explain it very well on my comment :)

Comment: It was the is.na that was confusing me so i ran it without that part and it returned NA's - but i thought i'd check.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two steps solution.
First get an index vector of the values you want, then use that index vector to subset the dataframe.

```
inx <- sapply(new_dat[-1], function(x) {
  w <- which(x >= 2)
  if(length(w)) min(w) else NROW(x)
})
new_dat[inx, 1]
#[1] 0.06 0.11 0.06
```